# Why a particular page layout is broken when the template works fine with other content

Tags: html, css, layout, firebug

I have this one particular page: http://www.problemio.com/problems/problem.php?problem_id=230

It has broken layout. But the weird part is that I use this template with lots of different content and the columns never break like that.  Most of the time, the left and right column just align.

Any idea why this happens on this particular page? I can't locate the problem with firebug.

Thank

Comment: Well, it's difficult since your document [is invalid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.problemio.com%2Fproblems%2Fproblem.php%3Fproblem_id%3D230&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&st=1&outline=1&verbose=1). But it's probably a not closed/opened tag.

Comment: You shouldn't use firebug all the time when debugging.  If you have missing or extra tags sometimes firebug will fix those automatically and you won't find them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an unclosed DIV and this is breaking your layout and putting the right column into the left column. Firefox will automatically fix this for you so you may not be able to see this in firebug.

```
<div class="left">
<div class="right">
</div>
```

Viewing your source code is better than using firebug for this - as firebug shows you the DOM and the source is what your browsers sees before it renders the page.

Comment: this might be the answer but how about giving an exact location

Comment: If you inspect it in firebug, you'll see that the right column is inside the left column in the DOM.

Comment: It's actually the opposite... there is a closing div missing, that's why the right column is included in the left column)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are closing all your divs.  It looks to me like you are not closing all divs and therefore the right column becomes part of the left column div (instead of being a sibling).

To be exact, it looks like there is a `</div>` missing right before the comment `<!-- Closes left div -->`